# Vehicle color in Uber ride details

Tags: uber-api

Is there any way to get vehicle color in Uber API? I can't find any info about it in documentation (https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-get#response).

Are there any plans to add this info in future?

Comment: Since the documentation says about the whole `vehicle` object, _"only non-null during an ongoing trip"_, I rather doubt it ... the two most relevant parties, driver and passenger(s), are inside the vehicle already, so who'd need to know which color the car was from any API _now_ ...?

Comment: There is no info about vehicle color returned by any endpoint - and there are no plans to add it in the future.